# 0b01 ^ 0b10 = 0b1 (Google search result)

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation

If I Google search **`0b01 ^ 0b10`**, the result I get back by Google's result widget is **`0b1`**.

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something here?

I'm expecting an answer of **`ob11`**, based on these simple rules:

- `0 ^ 0` = `0`
- `1 ^ 1` = `0`
- `1 ^ 0` = `1`
- `0 ^ 1` = `1`

Comment: The google result widget interprets `^` as exponentiation

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @harold:

> The google result widget interprets `^` as exponentiation.

Took me a while to realize that.